# Java happend before thread start

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, jvm, java-memory-model

I read somewhere that starting a thread has some special effect on the happend before relationship. Now I'm not sure if my code gurantees the happend before relationship, so please enlighten me.

I have a Dispatcher thread and a Worker class implementing the `Runnable` interface. The Dispatcher thread creates a new instance of the Worker and fills a `LinkedList` in the Worker instance through the `add` method with elements.

Then the Dispatcher hands the Worker instance to a `ExecutorService` via the `execute` method.

Then the run method in the Worker class starts accessing and removing stuff from the `LinkedList`.

Does the freshly started instance of the Worker see the same state of the `LinkedList` as the Dispatcher left it in? Or could it be that `LinkedList` is in some inconsitent state? Will I have to fill the `LinkedList` in a sychronized method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Language Specification [writes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.4):

> An action that starts a thread *synchronizes-with* the first action in the thread it starts.
>
> If an action `x` *synchronizes-with* a following action `y`, then we also have `hb(x, y)`.
>
> If we have two actions `x` and `y`, we write `hb(x, y)` to indicate that `x` *happens-before* `y`.

However, from your description it is not clear whether that is relevant in your case, as you talk about an executor, but don't explain when that executor is created or its worker threads started.

What is relevant is the following exerpt from [Executor's JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html):

> Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to
>   submitting a `Runnable` object to an `Executor`
>   *happen-before* its execution begins, perhaps in another thread.

Hence your code is safe, as long as the dispatcher thread no longer accesses the list after submitting the `Runnable`.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentations: [ExecuterService javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

> Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a Runnable or Callable task to an ExecutorService happen-before any actions taken by that task, which in turn happen-before the result is retrieved via Future.get().

This means that your concept is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If there is locking or other synchronization primitives used, and you're just using a plain old ArrayList, then the two threads could see different states.

When coordinating work between two separate threads, you have to either use a thread-safe/concurrent data structure or use synchronization code to guarantee a consistent "memory snapshot" between the threads.

One of the reasons this is important is due to caching. The two threads, executing concurrently on different processors, could have cached some objects in different local registers (that are local to those processors).

Comment: Thanks, I though so. But the dispatcher shall never touch the data again. Would it be enough to pass a freshly created LinkedList through the constructor Worker(LinkedList<Blah> blahBlah). Constructors make a happend before relationship, don't they?

Comment: @Franz - Why not just let the worker thread create the lists, if all the dispatcher does is construct them? I'm not entirely sure if constructors do make a happened-before relation. In principle you might be right.

Comment: Damn, I was quite good at this stuff, it's amazing how fast knowledge rusts if left unused.